# SQLite - Autoincrement Primary Key (started from a specific value)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I need to create a table in SQLite (for android) where the AutoIncrement value starts from a specific value and not form 1, for example 100.

Here is an example of the create statement:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ESTADO (ID_ESTADO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,DESCRIPCION varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL);

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the sqlite [documentation](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

> SQLite keeps track of the largest ROWID that a table has ever held
> using an internal table named "sqlite_sequence". The sqlite_sequence
> table is created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table
> that contains an AUTOINCREMENT column is created. The content of the
> sqlite_sequence table can be modified using ordinary UPDATE, INSERT,
> and DELETE statements. But making modifications to this table will
> likely perturb the AUTOINCREMENT key generation algorithm. Make sure
> you know what you are doing before you undertake such changes.

You can update the sqlite_sequence table to your table autoincrement starts at 100 for example.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting first record, add the start value for the auto increment field. then all new records will start from that value.